# Oracle SQL: How to use CHECK Constraint to not allow overlap reservation dates

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, overlap, overlap2d

I am hanging on a problem

Imagine you are the manager of a hotel that has a database in its database

```
CREATE TABLE Hotel
       (roomnr SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        arrival DATE NOT NULL,
        departure DATE NOT NULL,
        guest CHAR (30),
        PRIMARY KEY (roomnr, arrival)
        CHECK (departure >= arrival));
```

Table with the following definition:

So you can not leave this hotel before you arrive.

Change this definition so that you can not enter a reservation in the table whose arrival date conflicts with an existing departure date.
Count as a collision

- both one-sided overlaps, e.g. 3.1.-6.1. already booked and 1.1.- 5.1. or 4.1.-10.1. than to reserve
- as well as bilateral overlaps, e.g. 2.1.-6.1. already booked and 1.1.- 10.1. or 3.1.-5.1. than to reserve.

Comment: If you don't get an exact answer, then it may not be possible to do this from a check constraint.  In that case, consider using a trigger instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support a built-in range datatype (as far as I know).  Hence, it does not have built-in overlap functionality.

In order to implement such a check, you have two choices:

- Create a user-defined function that checks for overlaps.  Use this function in a check constraint.
- Write a trigger that checks for overlaps.

(The second can be tricky in Oracle because of mutating table errors.)  I think you need to write a function to use in a check constraint.

Comment: Running Oracle 19c, I don't think it's possible to call a user-defined function from a check constraint. At least I couldn't make it work.